# white spaces in BindItem textbox

Tags: c#, entity-framework, textbox

Maybe it's a silly mistake, I would like to understand why there are white spaces in my textbox.
[Texbox with white spaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWSFv.png)

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxbCreateAdress" runat="server" Text="<%# BindItem.Adress%>"></asp:TextBox>
```

In my SQL database, this field is like this : 
Adress (char(50), NULL)

I used entity Framework and to match with database, I wrote in my entity class :

```
[StringLength(50)]
[Column(TypeName = "char")]
public string Adress { get; set; }
```

I tried to delete the "StringLenght" or replace with "MaxLenght" but it doesn't change anything.
I think that white spaces represent the last 50 characters.

It's a problem, because if a user add a character in textbox, there is a "too many characters" exception.
I could add a "MaximumValue" in textbox declaration but it's not a solution for white space.

Do you have an idea?

Comment: Your column should be nvarchar or varchar. Char will fill the whole column with fixed length space...

Comment: If you change the column type the space in existing entries will remain, however any new entries won't have this behavior.

Comment: Ok because I can't change the database column, this is fixed

Comment: You can use RTRIM() in your select statement to get past this... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql  eg `SELECT RTRIM(Address) AS Address FROM [Table]`

Comment: Thank you for your idea but I don't use select statement, just a definition in my bindItem and viewModel. I had to specify "typeName = char"  otherwise my entity didn't fit with existing database